# URL HelpTopic in ExcelDNA

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-dna

I have the following method written in VB .Net:

```
<ExcelFunction(Description:="Test", HelpTopic:="http://www.google.co.za")>
   Public Shared Function HelloWorld2(<ExcelArgument(Name:="First parameter",       Description:="Cool Function")> ByVal sString As String) As String
    Return "Hello World2, from a DLL... " & sString
End Function
```

As you can see the HelpTopic is set to a URL, when I run this program and click on "Help On This Function', it says Help Reference is not valid.

Is it possible to have a Helptopic on the internet, where a Function in excel can access it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel added support for this in Excel 2010, and you also need [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) v. 0.30 to support internet URLs. Excel did not support this in feature in earlier versions.